# Resize HTML column and resize whole table to match div

Tags: html, css

I got a div serving as a header and below it a table that acts as a post, with a title, body and one cell and/or colums that hass arrows and a counter for upvotes and downvotes.
First problem I have is alignment and second resizing colums

Here is my code

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;

}

th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#votes {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50% ;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>RANDOM THINGS</div>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th id="title">Title</th>
      <th id="votes" rowspan="3">
        <img src='images/arrow_up.png' onclick='Upvote()'/>

        <br>0<br>

        <img src='images/arrow_down.png' onclick='Downvote()'/>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="textBody">
      <td rowspan="2">Text Body</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[What I got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6tYl.png)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a table for this? Normally you would not. Also, could be more specific about your alignment and column resizing issues. It is not clear as to what is not aligning with what nor what you expect from resizing - which elements, how, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the div so it doesn't expand it's width in order to add the padding.

If using `border-box` the width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border.

Your css would end up as:

```
div {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50% ;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The rest of it unchanged. Here you have a CodePen showcasing it: https://codepen.io/javierojeda/pen/LqpLVN

However, as @hungerstar mention... You wouldn't use a table for that kind of things. You may want to use the new `display: grid`, `display: flex` or even use 3 divs and some CSS to accommodate them as you need.

For more info:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I will attempt the same with grid, that is better, but I just kinda started with this and dont feel like changing it all
Plus I need a php script that will add another such table basiclly add another post which you can upvote, and I dont know how that would work with grid... here I just create a new table with the stuff Iget using php keys from inputs in a form and use that. If you have a better idea I would love to hear it